# PHP Error - Login Script

Tags: php, sql, authentication

I am creating a new login script/members directory.

I am creating it from scratch without any frameworks (advice on this matter would also be appreciated).

The situation:

```
// Look up the username and password in the database
    $query = "SELECT admin_id, username FROM admin WHERE adminname = '$admin_user' AND password = SHA1('$admin_pass')";
    $data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($data) == 1) {
```

This bit of code keeps giving me an error (the last line in particular):

```
Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /home8/craighoo/public_html/employees/security/dir_admin.php  on line 20
```

When echoing the query I get:

```
SELECT admin_id, adminname FROM admin WHERE adminname = 'admin' AND password = SHA1('password')
```

EDIT:
Thanks to everyone. The problem was in my Database column names and the column names I was referencing.

Comment: I'm assuming you're using PHP sessions (if not you should be!) make sure to run a  session_regenerate_id()  after a successful login to prevent a known exploit.

Comment: Instead of running SHA hashing within the database, I suggest you use PHP's SHA function, especially if the database server is on another box, because you are sending their password as plain text from the web server to the database, even though it's inside your network, it's still a hole.

Comment: Sidenote: You might want to take a look at prepared statements ( http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php ) to avoid SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Thanks TravisO! I will keep this stuff in mind going forward.  I might need significantly more help in that area when the time comes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query execution is failing. When that happens `mysqli_query` returns `false` (boolean value) and when is passed to `mysqli_num_rows`, you get this error.

Print the query just before executing and check for correctness.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the original question and am looking at my SQL now.

Comment: Fixed it. Thanks for the reminder, sometimes I forget the basic rules of debugging.

Answer (score 2):

Considering that [**`mysqli_query`**](http://fr.php.net/mysqli_query) returns `false` on failure, and that $data is a boolean, here, I suppose there is an error occuring during the execution of your SQL query.

You could try using [**`mysqli_error`**](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) to find out what this error is :

```
$data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
if ($data !== false) {
    // Do whatever you want with $data
    if (mysqli_num_rows($data) == 1) {
        // 
    }
} else {
    echo mysqli_error($dbc);
    die;
}
```

Note : echoing the error message and dying, like I did here, is OK while developping your script ; but you should not do that in production.

Instead, in production, you should :

- Log the error to a file
- Display a nice message to the user

Comment: Thanks, I updated the original question and am looking at my SQL now.

Comment: Glad to see you fixed your problem :-)

Answer (score 1):

When you have a critical query, it's best to add a die to it like so:

```
mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die('Critical error on line #'. __LINE__ .' when attempting to login ...<br>'. mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running that same query manually thru phpmyadmin or the console? What result do you get?